# .htaccess only allow access to directory when coming through the right url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

**Case**:

I have a website www.xyz.com/ with folder / abc

I have made a subdomain abc.xyz.com which points (on the webserver) to the /abc folder

I would like to make it impossible for people to access www.xyz.com/abc and be redirected to abc.xyz.com

**tried**

a normal 301 redirect results in people also being redirected when they go to abc.xyz.com (so error for too many redirects).

Thank you.

Comment: Can you paste the `.htaccess` you have tried with

Answer (score 0):

I got it after a few trials and errors:

Redirect 301 /abc/ https://abc.xyz.com